# BeautifulSoup + xlwt : Put the content of a HTML table in Excel

Tags: python, html, excel, beautifulsoup, html-table

I am trying (with a little python script) to put the content of a HTML table from a online webpage in an Excel sheet.

All is working well, except the "Excel thing".

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# --*-- coding:UTF-8 --*--

import xlwt
from urllib2 import urlopen
import sys
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import urllib

def BULATS_IA(name_excel):
    """ Function for fetching the BULATS AGENTS GLOBAL LIST"""

 ws = wb.add_sheet("BULATS_IA") # I add a sheet in my excel file

    Countries_List = ['United Kingdom','Albania','Andorra']
    Longueur = len(Countries_List)
    number = 1 


    print("Starting to fetch ...")

    for Countries in Countries_List:
        x = 0
        y = 0

        print("Fectching country %s on %s" % (number, Longueur))
        number = number + 1
        htmlSource = urllib.urlopen("http://www.cambridgeesol.org/institutions/results.php?region=%s&type=&BULATS=on" % (Countries)).read()
        s = soup(htmlSource)
        **tableauGood = s.findAll('table')
        try:
            rows = tableauGood[3].findAll('tr')
            for tr in rows:
                cols = tr.findAll('td')
                y = 0
                x = x + 1
                for td in cols:
                    hum =  td.text

                    ws.write(x,y,td.text)
                    y = y + 1
                    wb.save("%s.xls" % name_excel)**

        except (IndexError):
            pass

    print("Finished for IA")



name_doc_out = raw_input("What do you want for name for the Excel output document ? >>> ")
wb = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8')
print("Starting with BULATS Agents, then with BULATS IA")
#BULATS_AGENTS(name_doc_out)
BULATS_IA(name_doc_out)
```

-- 
So anything is going in the Excel Sheet, but when I print the content of the var ... I see what I should see !

I'm trying to fix it since one hour but I still don't understand what's going one. 
If some of you can give me a hand, It should be VERY nice.

Comment: I can't understand what the problem actually is. Could you please expand on the "-- So anything is going in the Excel Sheet, but when I print the content of the var ... I see what i should see ! " sentence, please.

Comment: Sorry ! I mean that hum (which is equal to td.text) return me the values that I want to put in the excel sheet (when I print it, I see what I want to write in the excel sheet).

Comment: ws.write(x,y,td.text) is actually returning me this error : ValueError: column index (257) not an int in range(256)

Comment: I just tried your script fixing the file encoding to "# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-" and removing those asterisks next to wb.save and before tableauGood: it works fine. I'm not sure that it will matter but what Python version are you using?

Comment: 2.7.1 ... It seems to work when I put wb.save just after ws.write. So the data is well written in the excel sheet but now, when the script go trough the second country with Institutions to pull in the Excel I get this error :  Exception: Attempt to overwrite cell: sheetname=u'BULATS_IA' rowx=1 colx=0
x was incremented so I don't understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have try your application. And I am very sure that the output of td.text is same as the excel file. So what's your question? If the content is not what you want, you should check the  usage of BeautifulSoap. 
Further more, you may need to do following:

```
           for td in cols:
                hum =  td.text.replace("&nbsp;", " ")
                print hum
                ws.write(x,y,hum)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help guys ! It seems to work now ... I don't know what was going on ... But I always get this error after the first country :
 Exception: Attempt to overwrite cell: sheetname=u'BULATS_IA' rowx=1 colx=0